# rolling mutate function applied to lists data frames

Tags: r

I have some time series data where I use the `rolling_origin` function to apply different time series splits to the data which generates a number of lists. The time series starts from 2020-03-01 until 2020-10-30.

I want to start from 2020-04-15 such that I have 1 month before (2020-03-15) and 1 month after (2020-05-15). I can use an `ifelse` statement to add a 1 for observations after and a 0 for observations before.

```
rolledData %>% 
  map(.,  ~mutate(.x,
    treatment_control = ifelse(date >= as.Date("2020-04-15"), 1, 0)
  ))
```

But what I want to do is to increment the `ifelse` date when mapped over the list. So the first one might start on the 2020-04-15 but in the next list in the sequence it would be changed to 2020-04-16, and the next list 2020-04-17, .... , until the end.

I could manually write out the results:

```
lst1 <- rolledData[[12]] %>% 
  mutate(
    treatment_control = ifelse(date >= as.Date("2020-04-15"), 1, 0)
  )

lst2 <- rolledData[[13]] %>% 
  mutate(
    treatment_control = ifelse(date >= as.Date("2020-04-16"), 1, 0)
  )

lst3 <- rolledData[[14]] %>% 
  mutate(
    treatment_control = ifelse(date >= as.Date("2020-04-17"), 1, 0)
  )
```

How can I `map` over the list and increment the `treatment_control` mutate?

Note: Because I am using financial data (which was just the easiest to obtain for a reproducible example) the weekends are removed (in my data I have a full week)

Data:

```
library(tidyquant)
library(rsample)
data <- tq_get(c("AAPL"),
               get  = "stock.prices",
               from = "2020-03-01",
               to   = "2020-10-30")

rolledData <- data %>% 
  rolling_origin(
    data = .,
    initial = 60, # 2 months of data
    assess = 0,
    cumulative = FALSE,
    skip = 0
  )

rolledData <- rolledData$splits %>% 
  map(., ~analysis(.x))
```

Comment: The only requirement is that the data contains 1 month before and 1 month after the mutate date. This is already controlled for since each data frame in the list contains 60 observations - so the "rolling date" is pretty much just taking the mid point of each of these data frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dates are different, we can pass a `vector` of custom dates that have the same `length` as the `rolledData` in `map2`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
rolleData2 <- rolledData %>% 
       map2(., newdates,
       ~ .x %>%
           mutate(treatment_control = +(date >= .y)
     ))
```

where

```
newdates <-  seq(as.Date("2020-03-15"), length.out = length(rolledData), by = "1 day")
```

---

If it is based on the next month from the first 'date' value

```
library(lubridate)
rolledData2 <- rolledData %>%
        map(~ .x %>%
                mutate(treatment_control =
           +(date >= (first(date) %m+% months(1)))))
```